# Python's threading and multiprocess lock not working

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have a toy example that demonstrates multithreading and locks. Without locks, I obviously get a bad value for the global `counter` variable. However, when I put in the `threading.Lock` in, it leads to even more inconsistencies. Also, `multiprocessing.Lock()` doesn't completely fix the problem either.

```
import threading 
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

num_experiments = 200
num_threads = 5 
iterations_in_one_thread = 500 

def f(): 

    global counter 
    for i in range(iterations_in_one_thread): 
        with lock: 
            counter += 1 

bad_count = 0 
# lock = threading.Lock()
lock = Lock() 

for x in range(num_experiments): 

    counter = 0 
    threads = [] 
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=f)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for i in threads: 
        t.join() 

    if counter != num_threads * iterations_in_one_thread: 
        bad_count += 1 
        print counter 


print "Bad count:", bad_count
print "Total runs:", num_experiments
```

Output I expect: `Bad count: 0` 
Output I get: `Bad count: 3` (or sometimes upto 6)

I'm on python 2.7.3

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

Comment: I get 0 running your code on Python 2.7.13 on Windows; without the lock I get 197 bad counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just made a simple typo.

```
for i in threads: 
    t.join()
```

should be

```
for i in threads: 
    i.join()
```

Otherwise, you're only joining on the last thread. Also, you probably shouldn't mix the multiprocessing library with the threading library. Stick with `threading.Lock`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, what a stupid mistake! Thanks a lot. Care to elaborate why using just the lock from multiprocessing would be bad?

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

`multiprocessing.Lock` is a close analog to `threading.Lock`, but they aren't identical. In such a simple use case, you're probably ok interchanging them, but in general, mixing things from `threading` and `multiprocessing` can lead to some interesting bugs that are tough to track down.